# Excel VBA with Index Match

Tags: excel, vba

Have been trying to solve below but no luck so far, seeking for your help :

1. vba formula return with extra two "@", how to fix the code or remove the "@" in cell R1?
2. If i want to do a loop and run the vba code from cell R1 to R30, which part of the code should i modify?

   ```
    Dim PartPoError As Range
    Dim PART As Range
    Dim PO As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long


      lastrow1 = Sheets("TEMPLATE").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
      x = "J" & lastrow1
      t = "A" & lastrow1
      V = "B" & lastrow1

      Set PartPoError = Sheets("rpt_sense").Range("A1", x)
      Set PART = Sheets("rpt_sense").Range("A1", t)
      Set PO = Sheets("rpt_sense").Range("B1", V)

      With Worksheets("rpt_sense")
        .Range(.Cells(2, 23), .Cells(lastrow1, 23)).ClearContents
        .Range(.Cells(2, 23), .Cells(lastrow1, 23)).Formula = "=A2&B2"
      End With

      lastrow2 = Sheets("template").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

      For s = lastrow2 To 16 Step -1
     If Sheets("template").Cells(s, 10).Value = "" Then

         ' Stuck in below formula error....it retunred with extra two "@" in cell formula R1.....

         Sheets("template").Cells(s, 10) = "=INDEX('rpt_sense'!r:r" & ",MATCH('template'!c8" & "&'template'!B" & s & ",'rpt_sense'!a:a" & "&'rpt_sense'!f:f" & ",0),1)"

        End If

        Next s
   ```

[picture file - index match id and date in yellow from another worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMi8J.jpg)

[picture 2 - data from another worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmUpG.jpg)

Comment: The addition of `@` in the formula isn't a mistake in itself. Excel adds this to control spill which may well be what you want. The real question is, does the formula work? Another one is whether you want the formula in the cell or its result. I'm always rather reluctant to get VBA to write a formula instead of doing the job itself (maybe using the same function).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your info and noted. The formula is not working with the extra "@", i need to replace it with a blank with CTRL + H. My reason of doing this  is because i got a range from R1 to R30 need to search and look up the data from another worksheet, and i am searching for better way to do this.

Comment: If you would tell us the lookup value, where the data are and where you want the result we might well come up with the code you want. But as things stand we just can't get a picture of what you need by looking at code that doesn't work. Try another approch of explaining your question.

Comment: What about `.Formula2` (e.g. `rng.Formula2 = "=..."`) ? @talentgreatness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need vba code if you want to find the sales and revenue by id and date:

Here is the formula for finding the sales based on two criteria:

=INDEX(Sheet2!C2:C3,MATCH(1,INDEX((Sheet3!ID(cell)=Sheet2!A2:A3)*(Sheet3!date(cell)=Sheet2!B2:B3),0,1),0))

here
1.Sheet2 = where your data is stored.
2.sheet3 = where you want to find the sales and revenues
3.Use ID as absoulte reference
3.Use date as relative reference.
Let me know is it worked or not.

Comment: Hi, i got this error prompt when insert the formula in cell: "There's a problem with this formula. Not trying to type a formula? When the first chracter is an equal (=) or minus (-) sign, excel thinks it's a formula................."

Comment: Can you share the file??

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your help, your video is cool and helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i don't understand fully what you wanted to do..Can you share screenshot with what your final output will be look like..

```
 Dim PartPoError As Range
Dim PART As Range
Dim PO As Range
Dim lastrow As Long


lastrow1 = Sheets("TEMPLATE").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 
'I think this variant variable is not required if you just want to use range.

x = "J" & lastrow1
t = "A" & lastrow1
V = "B" & lastrow1
'The change will be like this.
Set PartPoError = Sheets("rpt_sense").Range("A1","J" & lastrow1)
  Set PART = Sheets("rpt_sense").Range("A1", "A" & lastrow1)
  Set PO = Sheets("rpt_sense").Range("B1","B" & lastrow1)

  With Worksheets("rpt_sense")
 .Range(.Cells(2, 23), .Cells(lastrow1, 23)).ClearContents
 .Range(.Cells(2, 23), .Cells(lastrow1, 23)).Formula = "=A2&B2"
   End With

   lastrow2 = Sheets("template").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

   For s = lastrow2 To 16 Step -1
  If Sheets("template").Cells(s, 10).Value = "" Then
  'Please clear what actually you want to do here..
  ' Stuck in below formula error....it retunred with extra two "@" in cell formula R1.....

  Sheets("template").Cells(s, 10) = "=INDEX('rpt_sense'!r:r" & ",MATCH('template'!c8" & "&'template'!B" & s & ",'rpt_sense'!a:a" & "&'rpt_sense'!f:f" & ",0),1)"

 End If

 Next s
```

Comment: hi i have inserted a picture file on the above, i want to search data from another worksheet using index match with two criteria - id (single cell) and date (30/31 days)  with a loop, is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: So you want to search from a worksheet based on the ID = 123 and Date (01-Aug-20) right? So which pass both the criteria then that data need to paste in R1 column?? Can you provide your another screenshot of worksheet which contain the data??

Comment: hi i have provided picture 2 in above link, thanks for your assistance.